# failed to create p2p group with WifiP2pManager.createGroup()

Tags: android, wifip2p

our app uses WifiP2pManager.createGroup() to create p2p group and it worked normally on Samsung Note4.
But after we update it to L(version 5.01), it alwasy fail to create p2p group with that API.
We try our app in other devices with L release (Sony Z3, LG G3, HTC One M8) but do not find the same issue.
From logs, we found that there are wpa_supplicant errors after invoking that API.
Here is the related logs:

---

29471 D/GcWifiTransceiver(10202): [MGCC] createWifiP2pGroup
=> app triggered to create p2p group

29479 E/wpa_supplicant( 3649): Failed to create interface p2p-wlan0-0: -12 (Out of memory)
29480 E/wpa_supplicant( 3649): P2P: Failed to create new group interface
29481 E/wpa_supplicant( 3649): P2P: Delete the old group interface. Renew the group interface.
29492 I/wpa_supplicant( 3649): p2p-wlan0-0: Failed to start AP functionality
=> wpa_supplicant error

---

Full log can be downloaded from the following link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Dh-HEkJprWSlpUdW5GR3gzQWs
Could someone kindly help us check this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a problem with that one device model. Android isn't identical on every device - and Linux often suffers if the WiFi driver or Bluetooth driver have buys not found on other devices.